# TableView and UIImageView show incorrect layout unless scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, autolayout

i have a `TableView` where I have a `UIImageView` and text. When the table appears the layout is incorrect, but when scrolling the layout is correct.

The image is loading asynchronously and when load I add constraints, but not updated until scroll.

```
public func tableView
(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

    {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TimelineCellPhoto", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

                cell.photoImageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                cell.photoImageView?.clipsToBounds = true

                //IMAGEN
                var  imagen = newNotice.getImage()
                if(imagen == nil ){
                    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                         let url = NSURL(string: newNotice.getImageUrl())
                         self.getDataFromUrl(url!) { data in

                                imagen = UIImage(data: data!)!

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                                cell.setPostedImage(imagen)
                                cell.setNeedsLayout()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{

                    cell.setPostedImage(imagen)
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                }

                cell.postLabel?.text = newNotice.getText()
                cell.postLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

                cell.setNeedsLayout()
            return cell
        }
    }


internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {

        didSet {

            if oldValue != nil {
               photoImageView!.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
            }
            if aspectConstraint != nil {
                photoImageView!.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        aspectConstraint = nil
    }
    func setPostedImage(image : UIImage) {

        let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height

        aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: photoImageView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: photoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)

        photoImageView!.image = image
        photoImageView.setNeedsLayout()
    }
```

[image: My tableview it is like this]
[image: The table Display like this]
[image: I want like this]

Comment: Try to reload table data in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you. But this solution only works if I already have all the data, sometimes I "search" the information in a sendAsynchronousRequest, so when the call is answered i reloadTable for charge the data.

Comment: Have you resolved your Auto Layout issue?

Comment: For now i am using   self.tableView.beginUpdates() and                    self.tableView.endUpdates() when i charge the image, and this resolved the auto layout. But the only problem it s that i use self.tableView.beginUpdates when i scroll and add the other cells (  self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(arrayIndex, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade) and this not work very good when i scroll, but for the moment is my solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an iOS 8 issue where the initial width of a dequeued `tableViewCell` will be set to the storyboard's cell width, instead of the `tableView` width.

This affects the initial layout, but the cell will be laid out correctly once it reappears back on screen.

(What's happening behind the scenes is that the wrong cell width affects any contentView label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.)

A workaround is to set the cell's frame width to match the tableView's width. The cell will be laid out correctly from the start, without having to reload or scroll.

*You might also consider using a placeholder image until your image is loaded.  This will eliminate having to add and remove constraints for the imageView.  AFNetworking can handle asynchronously downloading and setting the image for you.*

**Update:**

It looks like you have too many vertical constraints.  If you have 3 vertical stacked items, you only need 4 vertical constraints to space them.

But I still believe it's a "width" issue and the label has a wrong `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.  Auto Layout thinks it initially needs ~9 lines to fit all the text, but when the cell scrolls back on screen, the width is now correct, and Auto Layout realizes it only needs 3 lines.

Comment: Thank . I try, but if placeholder is bigger than image  i have a space and when scroll fix it. Maybe i have the wrong constraint.

Comment: If the layout initially is incorrect, but scrolling fixes it, it's likely because the initial cell width is wrong, which leads to the label width being wrong.  Try setting the cell's width to the tableView width.

Comment: The cell's width is the same that the table width. Now i have space between text and bottom to the cell. I can fix the distance between image and text

Comment: One of your constraints might not be correct.  It would help if you could post your constraints, and an example of what you want the cell to look like.

Comment: Ok. I finally can add image with the constraints and with a example

Comment: You may want to delete all your vertical constraints, and only add ones that control spacing between one control and its neighbor (or container top/bottom).  And if you can learn how to code this with a single cell/placeholder, your code will be simpler and your table will perform better, since you won't be adding/removing constraints on the fly.